# Grub-update doesnt find the other OS anymore

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I installed Grub customizer. Unfortunetly I unticked search for other OS. This action worked and gub-update shows only the current ubuntu 11.04 (I have also Windows and another ubuntu installed). Afterwards I ticked the "search for other OS" again, but still grub-update shows only my ubuntu 11.04. Does anybody know how to "teach" grub to look again for other OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make grub recognise other OSes, `os-prober` needs to be installed and the related GRUB configuration file needs to be existent and executable.

Make sure you've `os-prober` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

Running `stat -c%A /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` should give `-rwxr-xr-x`. If it's not executable (i.e. missing the `x`), make it executable by running:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I discovered that by unticking the "search for other" OS the folder you mentioned was removed. I copied this folder back into the grub.d and voila. So it seems that grub customizer removes the os_prober folder but cant copy it back.